# React router on refresh breaks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, page-refresh

I am making a front end shopping cart using react and react-router. I am using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`.

I am routing to `/product/:id` and it renders a product component using the `props.match.params.id` by filtering the `:id` product from all products.

It works fine until the page is refreshed manually. Whereas all other pages reload fine when manually refreshed. the product page breaks down with error.

This is the Product route :

```
<Route path ="/product/:id" component = {ProductPage} />
```

And this is the ProductPage Component

```
const [currentImage, setImage] = useState(products.filter(item => item.id === searchId)[0].images[0]);
const [original, setOriginal] = useState(product.price[0].original);
const [offer, setOffer] = useState(product.price[0].offer);
const [size, setSize] = useState(product.price[0].size);


useEffect(()=>{
    setImage(products.filter(item => item.id === searchId)[0].images[0]);
    document.documentElement.scrollTo(0,0);

},[props.match.params.id])
```

When I manually refresh the ProductPage, I get errors **TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined**

How do I fix this issue??

ps: products is an array of objects